# How to get the index of an array by using a 2D Point with an offset in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, bitmap, gdi+

I am currently using C# to get Pixel info from a Bitmap by using the Lockbits method, like so:

```
BitmapData bmpData = bmpFromScreen2.LockBits(
                new Rectangle(0, 0, startDimensions.X, startDimensions.Y),
                ImageLockMode.ReadWrite,
                bmpFromScreen2.PixelFormat);
```

So far so good, then, I copy the bmpData to an array of bytes like so:

```
            IntPtr ptr = bmpData.Scan0;

            int bytes = Math.Abs(bmpData.Stride) * bmpFromScreen2.Height;
            byte[] rgbValues = new byte[bytes];

            Marshal.Copy(ptr, rgbValues, 0, bytes);
```

I know that I will get bytes in this fashion: Blue Green Red Blue Green Red... and so on.

Now here comes my problem: I need to get the RGB data of a specific Pixel by using bitmap coordinates.

For example:

Lets suppose I get rgbValues from 9 pixels like this:

```
255, 255, 0, 120, 222, 230, 15, 255, 0, 130, 255, 140, 50, 20, 20, 25, 115, 210, 170, 0, 0, 45, 50, 100, 90, 75, 120.
```

Lets (also) suppose these 9 pixels are in a 3x3 order, we could organize them like in "scans":

First Scan:

```
255, 255, 0, 120, 222, 230, 15, 255, 0
```

Second Scan:

```
130, 255, 140, 50, 20, 20, 25, 115, 210
```

Third Scan:

```
170, 0, 0, 45, 50, 100, 90, 75, 120
```

How can I get, for example, the index of Blue byte of Point (2,3)?

P.S This is my first question here, I apologize beforehand for any mistakes I could have made, I will learn!

Comment: is there a specific reason why you are using bitmapdata

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so, I found the answer to my problem, and what helped me was converting from a 2D array to 1D.

But, since I needed to use an offset of 3 (because the data stored 3 values for each pixel, and also considering I would need to get the two other channels from the reference of the first channel, I came up with this method:

```
public static byte GetIndexValue(byte[] array, Point point, int width, int channel)
        {
            int indexLoc = point.X + 3 + channel + point.Y * width;

            byte indexValue = array[indexLoc];

            return indexValue;
        }
```

Where:
**array** is obviously the array of bytes that stored the BitmapData.
**point** being the 2D X,Y point
**width** being the width of the array (I got this from when I calculated the size of the array by taking the BitmapData Stride)
**channel** being of value 0 for Red, 1 for Green, and 2 for Blue

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care for Performance to much:

```
Color pixelColor = bmpFromScreen2.GetPixel(x,y);
```